# Using Rel=Canonical Vs. Robots.txt Vs. META robots to prevent duplicate content indexing?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, duplicates

I want to construct a website I'm building in a way that would distinguish between visitors coming from organic sources (e.g, Google search), and paid sources (e.g, Google adwords).

Whenever a visitor would perform some sort of action, it would carry a string that would help me identify the source. I'm using PHP, and I suppose I would construct the website this way:

A. In general, all internal links in the website would never carry a string in their URL, so by default, every action would carry some default variable.

B. for paid traffic, visitors would reach a `domain.com/page.php?source=paid` type url, which would modify the default string to something else.

**My concern:**

I want to prevent Search engines form mistakenly index both `index.php` and `index.php?source=paid`, which could cause my website to allegedly have duplicate content and hurt my rankings.

if it matters, for the whole website, I want to use some re-write rule, making my links look cleaner, e.g, `domain.com/subscribe.php` -> `domain.com/subscribe`, so the solution needs to be compatible with this as well (in case it could hinder anything).

**I have thought about the following approaches to avoid this problem,
and would like to know which one should I pick, or combine, or whether there's an alternative:**

1. Simply place:

   `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/page.php" />` In the head of each `page.php`. according to [Google blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), Bing and Yahoo should also respect that. not sure though if that would 100% prevent pages from getting indexed, or just does something to "link juice".
2. Add this rule to robots.txt:
   `Disallow: /*?*` - Does this mean every url containg a `?` would never get indexed (such as `domain.com/page.php?source=paid`, but `domain.com/page.php` would indeed get indexed? I don't need to positively "allow" anything at the same time, right?
3. Use PHP IF/Else to do this:
   Check if the string `source` contains any value whatsoever. If it does, modify the `META robots` to `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />`.
   Else, (If it the url was reached without any string), modify the tag to be `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />`

Thanks!

Comment: I think only #1 makes sense, add a canonical references on the paid pages that link to the non-paid pages.

Comment: basically each paid page is the exact same file as the non-paid, only with an identifying string.

Comment: And hence the canonical reference :)

Comment: Ok:) I wonder why doesn't #2 makes sense? would it not work the way I mean?

Comment: This is a content problem, not an indexing problem per se; and if some pages are for paid users only, your server should redirect to a login page.

Comment: @Jack maybe I Wasn't clear enough - paid users are paid traffic (I'm paying search engines to get them, they don't pay anything). they should see exact same content as organic traffic.